# Hide class code?

Tags: php, class

Say I have the following, is this valid code? -

```
<?php

include_once('HelloWorld.class.php'); // contains class 'HelloWorld'

class user
{
     function hello() { 
         $HelloWorld = new HelloWorld; //Loads HelloWorld class into variable
         $HelloWorld->hello(); // calls hello function 
     }
}


$go = new user; // loads user class into variable 
$go->hello(); // calls user 'hello' function, which in turns utilizes 'HelloWorld' class


?>
```

Essentially, the "user" class utilizes another class.

What I am trying to achieve -

- I want to make the "user" class accessible and editable by someone (perhaps via a gui). They can edit the "user" class any way they see fit. However, I don't want them to be able to view the source of "HelloWorld.class.php". Is this possible?

Would they simply be able to retrieve the contents by? -

```
$lines = file("*path*\HelloWorld.class.php");
```

Comment: It's a bit redundant to re-init your `$HelloWorld` *every* time you call `hello()`, don't you think?

Comment: *Why* don't you want them to see the HelloWorld class code? If you let someone write code freely, almost all bets are off.

Comment: Is obfuscation the only option?

Comment: "`I want to make the "user" class accessible and editable by someone`". Just don't!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah but you could also write your engine separately and nest it, then make your public classes extend the engine. No need for all this classes instantiating other classes to avoid whatever it is you're avoiding.

I agree with the others in redundancy and the fact that you're letting anyone modify any class on your site. Unless you're Johnny McSuper-Coder then you won't want to deal with the security provisions you'll need to write into your user based update script to prevent them from just wrecking everything in any way they can.

I bet some decent planning would reveal any number of better options for your end goal. Not quite sure about how the SO community will feel if you generically post a question about how to go about doing whatever it is you're up to here though.